Are $\#Clique$ and $\#Coloring$ $\#\mathsf P$-hard on perfect graphs?
It is known that decision variants of these problems on perfect graphs are decidable in polynomial time.
But is counting the number of maximum cliques or optimal colorings $\#\mathsf P$-hard on perfect graphs? Or is it possible in polynomial time, just as the decision variants of the problems?
